# JS shorthand for if else

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I am trying to improve my coding skills, but I can not seem to figure this out. How do I write the following in shorthand?

```
/* fade */
$('.toggle-ui').on({
    'click': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var divToFade = ['#logo', '#hide-interface'];

        $.each(divToFade, function(intValue, currentElement) {
            // check alpha state and switch
            var currOp = $(currentElement).css('opacity');

            if (currOp == 1) $(currentElement).css('opacity', 0.5);
            if (currOp == 0.5) $(currentElement).css('opacity', 1);
        });
    }
```

Comment: *ternary operator* is shorthand for if-else in most programming languages.

Comment: i think u r looking for ternary Operator i.e. (test condition)?"successs result":"fail result";

Comment: @Sumant SMS slang sucks + use backsticks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
$(currentElement).css('opacity', currOp == 1 ? 0.5 : 1);
```

---

As a side note: I am used to using `===` over `==` to avoid accidental mistakes by unintended type coercion. To use it here, I would parse `currOp` to a number via `+`:

```
$(currentElement).css('opacity', +currOp === 1 ? 0.5 : 1);
```

For more information, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript).

Comment: Thank you. This was the syntax I was looking for. I was confused by the operators being inside the brackets. I was putting them on the outside.

Comment: @obmon do not radically change answers. If something isn't working downvote and comment. and for the record, `===` works just fine, you must have done something else wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Or i can edit it and put an explanation to the edit. currOp === 1 doesn't work. currOp == 1 works.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Uh.. I tried it. It didn't work. Removed one of the eq signs. It worked.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Stop changing it back. I am testing the code myself and 3 "=" DO NOT WORK.

Comment: Agreed! `.css()` returns a string, so it needs 2 `==` to evaluate the string to int and do the comparison.

Comment: @obmon please dont change the answers at your own. If something isnt working for you, either comment about it or ask the author for the clarification and let the answerer do the required changes.

Comment: why not? If I change it and put an explanation. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @Chips_100: your comments on the edit please, if it is correct or not.

Comment: you should be able to use three `=` if you first parse `currOp` to a number, i.e. by a `+`. So it would be `+currOp === 1`. `==` will automatically coerce the types to match, whereas `===` doesn't.

Comment: @obmon that's not your answer to change. Comment and let the author fix if needed, as is now the case.

Comment: Thats why it is better to ask the author for clarification rather than changing someone else's code. Maybe he's having some different logic

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj There is nothing wrong in *improving* someone else's answer, except if you care about his susceptibility... obmon has not been offensive by the way.

Comment: I think it was totally OK to edit my answer to have a working version (as tested by obmon) until I can personally react to the edit. I did not feel offended by anyone in any way, especially considering that my first code snippet did not work correctly. As you have seen, I added my explanation about `==` vs `===` when I had time do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do simple math:

```
$(currentElement).css('opacity', 1.5 - currOp);
```

Since

```
1.5 - 1.0 = 0.5
1.5 - 0.5 = 1.0
```

Comment: That would confuse me or anyone else when reading the code in the future i think..

Comment: @obmon It deserves an upvote though, really clever, +1.

Comment: @obmon Me too. I tend to avoid this kind of writing, but it's a viable, shorter solution.

Comment: @obmon Moreover, a small comment would be helpful enough : `// currOp = 1 or .5`.